# Adding hardcoded row in sql if value was not found by search

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table that goes something like this:
[image]

And I have selects....

```
  SELECT colors,
  COUNT (Num1) AS number1,
 COUNT (Num2) AS number2,
  COUNT (Num3) AS number3,
  COUNT (Num4) AS number4
  From table
  Group By colors
```

Result would be:

[image]

My question is: 
If there weren't some of the shown colors, how do I add a row at the end of the results containing that color with counts (0 0 0 0)?
Note: All colors must be shown in results, but not all colors have to be written in table

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` to subquery that returns all possible colors:

```
SELECT s.color, 
      COUNT (t.Num1) AS number1,
      COUNT (t.Num2) AS number2,
      COUNT (t.Num3) AS number3,
      COUNT (t.Num4) AS number4
FROM (-- subquery or table of all possible colors
) s
LEFT JOIN table t
  ON s.color = t.color
GROUP BY s.color;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RDWIV65204)**

**EDIT:**

Or using UNION ALL:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.color, 
          COUNT (t.Num1) AS number1,
          COUNT (t.Num2) AS number2,
          COUNT (t.Num3) AS number3,
          COUNT (t.Num4) AS number4
    FROM table t
    GROUP BY t.color
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT color, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM (--table or subquery) s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM cte c
                  WHERE c.color = s.color);
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/BOOL67843)**

Comment: And how would you just add new row at the bottom of results:
e.g. 
red 0 0 0 0

Comment: @MartinŠutalo Please check my demo, there is row `red 0 0 0 0`. You take color from color table, and count has matches so you get 0.